# How to Get Current Year with MDX Query?

Tags: mdx

I have little thing about MDX.
Is there any way to get current year from the system/server with MDX query?
I didn't have any dimension related to date or something like that.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a member and define it as 'YEAR(NOW())'

```
Member [Measures].[Current Year] as 'YEAR(NOW())'
```

Here is a more [complete sample](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301537)

```
-- The First Calculated member is the value of NOW()
WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[Full Date] as 'NOW()'
-- The Second Calculated Member is the Day part of the first calculated member.
MEMBER [Measures].[What Day] as 'DAY([Full Date])'
-- The Third Calculated Member is the Month part of the first calculated member.
MEMBER [Measures].[What Month] as 'MONTH([Full Date])'
-- The Fourth Calculated Member is the Year part of the first calculated member.
Member [Measures].[What Year] as 'YEAR([Full Date])'
SELECT
   {[Full Date],[What Day],[What Month],[What Year]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Your Cube]
```