# How to select current year in MDX query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I want in MDX:

```
-- T-SQL

SELECT
IIF(cal.CalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 0) AS ComputedColumn
FROM dim.Application app
JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON cal.DateID = app.ApplicationDateID
```

I've tried just to select in MDX ApplicationDateID in current year:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Application].[ApplicationDateID]}
FROM [DWH OLAP]
WHERE [Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[StrToMember("+Format(now(), “yyyy”)+”)]
```

which raises a parser error.

> Parser: The statement dialect could not be resolved due to ambiguity.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Current Year with MDX Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371904/how-to-get-current-year-with-mdx-query)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the StrToMember function around the complete address of the member:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Application].[ApplicationDateID] ON 1
FROM [DWH OLAP]
WHERE 
  StrToMember("[Calendar].[CalendarYear].&[(" + Format(now(), 'yyyy') + ")]";
```

ps

Is this really a measure in your cube?! "[Measures].[Application].[ApplicationDateID]" ..... standard way to create measures is a single level hierarchy

Comment: I've tried to use the function around complete address, but you're right. ApplicationDateId is not a measure. However, I'm still not sure how to rewritte the t-sql query, I'm new to mdx.